# Display number of rows in tableview section based on enum from JSON

Tags: json, swift

I have tableview that retrieves data from a JSON file. My goal is to create four sections ["Course", "Guide", "Article", & "Interview"] in my tableview. If an object has a type called "course" then I would like that object to be displayed in the Course section and so on.

What I have so far are four sections and the data ready to be displayed but I do not know how to count how many objects there are for each **type** object and add them to the number of row in section function.

My json file looks like this:

```
{
 "resources": [
{
  "title": "Cooking with Me",
  "url": "https://google.com",
  "type": "course",
  "date": "2020",
  "author": "Chef A"
},
{
  "title": "Daily Cooking",
  "url": "https://google.com",
  "type": "guide",
  "date": "2020",
  "author": "Chef B"
},
{
  "title": "Simple Recipes",
  "url": "https://google.com",
  "type": "guide",
  "date": "2020",
  "author": "Chef C"
}
 ]
}
```

// Model

```
struct Resources: Codable {
let resources: [Resource]
}

// MARK: - Resource
struct Resource: Codable {
let title: String
let url: String
let type: TypeEnum
let date, author: String
}

enum TypeEnum: String, Codable {
case article = "article"
case course = "course"
case guide = "guide"
case interview = "interview"
}
```

// View Controller

```
class ResourcesController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

//MARK: - Properties
var items = [Resource]()

//MARK: - IBOutlets
@IBOutlet weak var resourceTable: UITableView!

// MARK: - View Life Cycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    retrieveDate()
    
}

//MARK: - Methods
func retrieveDate() {
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "freeResources", withExtension: "json")!)
       let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(Resources.self, from: data)
        items = decoded.resources
        resourceTable.reloadData()
    } catch { print(error) }
}

//MARK: - Tableview Data Source
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 4
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if section == 0 {
        
        return "Courses"
    } else if section == 1 {
        return "Guides"
    } else if section == 2 {
        return "Articles"
    } else {
        return "Interview"
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sourceCell", for: indexPath) as! SourceCell
    
    cell.authorLabel.text = items[indexPath.row].author
    cell.titleLabel.text = items[indexPath.row].title
    return cell 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the items in your enum `TypeEnum` in the same order you want your sections (which you already have as it seems) then you can make the enum conform to `CaseIterable` which means you can get an array of all items and use that.

```
enum TypeEnum: String, Codable, CaseIterable {
    case article = "article"
    case course = "course"
    case guide = "guide"
    case interview = "interview"
}
```

Now you can get the count in one line

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.filter { $0.type == TypeEnum.allCases[section]}.count
}
```

And when creating the cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sourceCell", for: indexPath) as! SourceCell
    let type = TypeEnum.allCases[indexPath.section]
    let item = items.filter { $0.type == type }[indexPath.row]
    cell.authorLabel.text = item.author
    cell.titleLabel.text = item.title
    return cell 
}
```

You can also change the section count function to have more future proof code

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return TypeEnum.allCases.count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An efficient way is to create another struct for the sections

```
struct Section {
    let name : String
    let items : [Resource]
}
```

and an appropriate data source array

```
var sections = [Section]()
```

In `retrieveDate` group the array with `Dictionary(grouping:by:)` by `type` and map it to an array of `Section`

```
func retrieveDate() {
    do { 
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "freeResources", withExtension: "json")!)
        let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(Resources.self, from: data)
        let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: decoded.resources, by: {$0.type})
        sections = grouped.map({ (key, value) -> Section in
            return Section(name: key.rawValue.capitalized + "s", items: value)
        })
        resourceTable.reloadData()
    } catch { print(error) }
}
```

And change the table view data source methods to

```
//MARK: - Tableview Data Source
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return sections[section].name
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sections[section].items.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sourceCell", for: indexPath) as! SourceCell
    let item = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
    cell.authorLabel.text = item.author
    cell.titleLabel.text = item.title
    return cell 
}
```

Note: `type` as enum makes actually no sense just for parsing the JSON and if the JSON file is in the bundle anyway I recommended to refactor the structure to group the data already in the file for example

```
[{"name":"Guides",
 "items": [
    {"title": "Daily Cooking", "url": "https://google.com", "date": "2020", "author": "Chef B"},
    {"title": "Simple Recipes", "url": "https://google.com", "date": "2020", "author": "Chef C"}
]},
{"name":"Courses",
 "items": [
    {"title": "Cooking with Me", "url": "https://google.com", "date": "2020", "author": "Chef A"}
]}
]

// MARK: - Resource
struct Resource: Codable {
    let title: String
    let url: String
    let date, author: String
}

struct Section : Decodable {
    let name : String
    let items : [Resource]
}

...

sections = try JSONDecoder().decode([Section].self, from: data)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want these separated then you're going to need to create an array for each type.

```
var article = [Resource]()
var course = [Resource]()
var guide = [Resource]()
var interview = [Resource]()
```

Then return the count for each section:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch section {
case 0:
    return article.count
case 1:
return guide.count
case 2:
return interview.count
case 3:
}
```