# Attempt to insert row with tableView section swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

I am trying to insert rows into my `tableView` but I got a crash saying:

> Attempt to insert row 2 into section 1, but there are only 2 rows in
> section 1 after the update.

Here is my code:

```
var periods = [Date: [Model]]()
var mySec = 0

func showData([Date: [Model]], hasMore: Bool) {
    let oldSize = self.periods.map { $0.key }.sorted(by: { $0 > $1 }).count
            let oldVal = self.periods.flatMap { $0.value }.count

            reports.forEach { self.periods[$0] = $1 }
            let newSize = self.periods.map { $0.key }.sorted(by: { $0 > $1 }).count
            let newVal = self.periods.flatMap { $0.value }.count
            var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
            
            for section in 0..<(newSize - oldSize) {
                self.mySec = section + 1
                for count in 0..<(newVal - oldVal) {
                    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: count + oldVal, section: self.mySec)
                    
                    indexPaths.append(indexPath)
                }
                self.mySec += 1
            }
            
            self.customView.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.customView.tableView.insertSections(IndexSet(integer: 0), with: .bottom)
            self.customView.tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .bottom)
            self.customView.tableView.endUpdates()

            self.customView.noResultsLabel.isHidden = !reports.isEmpty
            self.customView.tableView.backgroundView = nil
            guard reports.isEmpty else { return }
            self.customView.tableView.backgroundView = self.emptyStateView
}
```

My table view:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        let index: [[Model]] = self.periods.map { $0.value }
        return index[section].count
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.mySec - 1
    }
```

Comment: Your data model is horrible. Use a custom struct for the sections. This solves your issue by the way. Consider that `numberOfRowsInSection` is called very often so *doing math* in this method is pretty inefficient.

Comment: I agree doing maths here is inefficient but How do I achieve the struct?

Comment: Please see this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62963246/display-number-of-rows-in-tableview-section-based-on-enum-from-json/62965431#62965431